# visual studio lnk2019 and 1120 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a class and a separate .cpp file with a main method. I get this when trying to compile

```
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>lab8.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall         teams::teams(void)" (??0teams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1    unresolved externals
```

The name of the class is "teams"
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

you have a missing default constructor.

with some experience you'll learn to read error messages.

cheers & hth.,

Comment: More specifically, you have declared, but not defined a default constructor - otherwise it would be automatically defined, or it would be a compile, rather than link, error.

Comment: I was a little confused since in java the default constructor is defined automatically